# Make a jquery 1.8 script to use jquery 3.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, infinite-scroll

I have a script infinite-scroll which was build with jquery 1.8.3 but it does not work on the site which is using jquery 3.1.1, I need this script to start using 3.1.1 because my site bootstrap modal uses 3.1.1 and i cannot drop the 3.1.1.
here is the app

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').infinitescroll({
        navSelector: "#next:last",
        nextSelector: "#next:last",
        itemSelector: "#content",
        debug: false,
        dataType: 'html',
    maxPage: 6,
        path: function(index) {
            return "index" + index + ".html";
        }
        // appendCallback   : false, // USE FOR PREPENDING
    }, function(newElements, data, url){
      // used for prepending data
        // $(newElements).css('background-color','#ffef00');
        // $(this).prepend(newElements);
    });
});
```

and the js class is located here 
    http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/infinite-page-scroll/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery no-conflict() has solved this issue